# Validacion Error asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Les comento que estoy realizando como una validación en mi formulario, donde dice `lbldiasfaltantes` se está guardando un valor cualquier número, puede ser del 1 al -31 y yo quiero que si en mi `label` sea <= 5 los campos se habiliten y si es mayor se inhabiliten.

Ese es mi código pero me sale un error subrayadado de rojo

```
if ((lbldiasfaltantessss.Text) <= 5)
{
    TxtMontoPagado.Enabled = true;
    TxtFecha.Enabled = true;
    BtnActualizar.Enabled = true;
    BtnBuscar.Enabled = true;
    BtnnoConforme.Enabled = true;
    dprAgencia.Enabled = true;
    dprTarea.Enabled = true;
    lblagencia.Enabled = true;
    lblTarea.Enabled = true;
    lblagencia.Enabled = true;
    txtNumeroRecibo.Enabled = true;
    TxtFechaPago.Enabled = true;
}
else if ((lbldiasfaltantessss.text) > 5)
{

    TxtMontoPagado.Enabled = false;
    TxtFecha.Enabled = false;
    BtnActualizar.Enabled = false;
    BtnBuscar.Enabled = false;
    BtnnoConforme.Enabled = false;
    dprAgencia.Enabled = false;
    dprTarea.Enabled = false;
    lblagencia.Enabled = false;
    lblTarea.Enabled = false;
    lblagencia.Enabled = false;
    txtNumeroRecibo.Enabled = false;
    TxtFechaPago.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: `if ( Convert.ToInt32(lbldiasfaltantessss.Text) <= 5)`

Comment: La propiedad Text `(lbldiasfaltantessss.Text)` devuelve un `string` y lo estás comparando con `5`, que es un entero.

Comment: No comprendo el por qué se votó para cierre esta pregunta, es muy específica y tiene los elementos necesarios para ser una buena pregunta. Sería bueno que el usuario que votó para cierre nos explique sus comentarios, igual y me estoy perdiendo de algo.

Comment: =\ @Flxtr al revisar la [edición](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/55568/revisions) habrás visto que el OP no incluyó el **código corregido que pusiste**. _Existía un error sintáctico y que por eso lo reporté. O dime tú, si encuentro una pregunta con código errónea se debe corregir siempre._

Comment: @Davlio ah muy bien (bueno, yo solo edite el código poniéndolo identado) :) siempre es bueno aclarar el por qué de situaciones así :) ahora que la pregunta está más completa no sé si consideres retirar tu voto, eso ya queda a decisión tuya. Saludos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como bien te dicen en los comentarios, la propiedad *.Text* de los controles ***Label*** en *asp.net* son de tipo *string* por lo cual para poder hacer cualquier tipo de comparación numérica al respecto, previamente deberás hacer algún tipo de casteo o parseo de este *string*.
Yo te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

```
    //Definir una variable de tipo entero sobre la cual se 
    //establecera la cantidad de dias faltantes obtenidos si es 
    //que el usuario ingresa un valor convertible a int32
    int diasFaltantes = 0;

    //TryParse lo que hara es justamente intentar parsear el texto de lbldiasfaltantessss.Text
    //a un int32 y setearlo en la variable diasFaltantes, que establecimos en la funcion como
    //parametro de salida con la palabra reservada out            
    int.TryParse(lbldiasfaltantessss.Text, out diasFaltantes);


    //En caso de que la conversion anterior no fuera posible, el sistema no 
    //arrojará ninguna excepcion y a su vez el valor de la variable diasFaltantes seguira en 0
    //mientras que si lo puede parsear, el valor parseado correspondiente estará en la variable diasFaltantes
    if (diasFaltantes<=5)
    {
        //Aquí va el código para HABILITAR los campos
    }
    else
    {
        //Aquí va el código para DESHABILITAR los campos
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Solo te falta parsear el `label` que es de tipo `string` a tipo entero para poder hacer tu comparación:

```
if ( int.Parse(lbldiasfaltantessss.Text) <= 5)
{ 
    //habilitados 
} else 
{ 
    //inhabilitados 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Estimado, su código debiera quedar como se muestra más abajo. Saludos.

```
if (int.Parse(lbldiasfaltantessss.Text) <= 5)
{
    TxtMontoPagado.Enabled = false;
    TxtFecha.Enabled = false;
    BtnActualizar.Enabled = false;
    BtnBuscar.Enabled = false;
    BtnnoConforme.Enabled = false;
    dprAgencia.Enabled = false;
    dprTarea.Enabled = false;
    lblagencia.Enabled = false;
    lblTarea.Enabled = false;
    lblagencia.Enabled = false;
    txtNumeroRecibo.Enabled = false;
    TxtFechaPago.Enabled = false;
}
```